# Close Google Map InfoWindows from fragement

Tags: java, android, google-maps, infowindow

I am trying to figure out a way to close an open Google Map Marker InfoWindow from another visible fragment by clicking on a button.

An InfoWindow can be closed by simply call [marker.HideInfoWinow()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#hideInfoWindow())

But this assumes you have access to the marker, which I do not have from within the Fragment.

I also read that only one InfoWindow can be open at a time so I was hoping that the map had a method to determine which marker's infowindow was open.

I know to use callback interface to communicate between the map fragment, the activity, and the other fragment.